# After installing Android studio - doesn't works and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I had Eclipse Juno with java 6 and 7 with Android plug-in, and everything worked just fine.
After I downloaded Android studio from the official site and installed it, on first launch nothing happens.
After I uninstalled the Android studio the Eclipse suddenly doesn't work, I see the slash window and after 2 seconds it shuts down and nothing happens.

I cannot understand the connection between these 2 events.
What can I do? i wont both working

Comment: you may need to re-install SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that android studio wasn't running because you didn't have the JDK_HOME environment variable set (I guess you are using Windows). Concerning the Eclipse, I don't see how the two can be connected. A system restart maybe could help!